# how to change CHAR length from 8 to 2 in R

Tags: r

I am working on .xpt file where one of the column 'name'  the char length is already set as 8, but I want to change it to 2. How to accomplish this in R

I have stored .xpt data into df1

**.xpt**

```
df1<-
date        name           expenditure      type
23MAR2013   KOSH           4000             COMPANY
23MAR2013   JOHN           800              INDIVIDUAL
24MAR2013   KHAN           300              INDIVIDUAL
24MAR2013   JASINT         8000             COMPANY
25MAR2013   KOSH           2000             COMPANY
25MAR2013   JOHN           220              INDIVIDUAL
25MAR2013   S KHAN         300              INDIVIDUAL
26MAR2013   S KHAN         300              INDIVIDUAL
```

The below Code that does not work for me:

```
df1$name <- substr(df1$name, 1, 1)
```

Could someone assist me in fixing this issue?

Comment: `substr(df1$name, 1, 2)`. You want length 2, not length 1.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, Apologise, I wrongly mentioned the code, My original code was `df1$name <- substr(df1$name, 2, 2)`. But it still does not work.. I want the length to be 2

Comment: Check my first comment again, carefully. Your code is *still* different; you’ve merely swapped one mistake for another.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I am not sure what you're referring to. Could you please help me with more clarification?

Comment: I don’t really know how to make this clearer. You wrote `substr(df1$name, 2, 2)`. I wrote `substr(df1$name, 1, 2)`. These two are different (check the numbers!).